# "Does not apply" category frequencies are much higher than the frequencies of any other category in the variable

Tags: categorical-data, missing-data, survey

I'm working with the data from a national survey. In some of the variables frequencies for "does not apply" category are much higher than for any other response in the variable.

Do I just ignore the frequencies in the "does not apply" category? Can they bias my analysis?